# Implicit Diff. I tried doing this problem two ways. I am unable to get the solutions to match each other. Is one of them incorrect?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I tried doing this problem two ways.   I am unable to get the solutions to match each other.  Is one of them incorrect?

[image]

Comment: on the left side derivation it looks like $xy$ became $x-y$ in the third line

Comment: That was it.  They are both equal results now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On your 3rd line in the first column, $x-y$ should be $xy$.

Comment: That was it.  They are both equal results now.

Answer (score 1):

$$y+\sqrt{xy}=1$$
$$y+\sqrt{x}\sqrt{y}=1$$
$$y'+\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}\sqrt{y}+\frac{y'}{2\sqrt{y}}\sqrt{x}=0$$
$$y'(1+\frac{\sqrt{x}}{2\sqrt{y}})+\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}\sqrt{y}=0$$
$$y'=\frac{-\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}\sqrt{y}}{1+\frac{\sqrt{x}}{2\sqrt{y}}}=\frac{-y}{2\sqrt{xy}+x}=\frac{y}{2y-2-x}$$

Answer (score 1):

$\begin{array}\\
y+\sqrt{xy}=1\\
\sqrt{xy}=1-y\\
xy = (1-y)^2\\
xy'+y = -2y'(1-y)\\
y = -y'(2-2y+x)\\
y' = \dfrac{-y}{2-2y+x)}\\
\end{array}
$

To get $y$ explicitly,
$xy = (1-y)^2
= 1-2y+y^2
$
so
$y^2-(2+x)y+1 = 0$.

Solving
$y
=\dfrac{2+x\pm\sqrt{x^2+4x+4-4}}{2}
=\dfrac{2+x\pm\sqrt{x^2+4x}}{2}
$.

Another explicit formula for $y$.
From $y+\sqrt{xy}-1=0$,
using the quadratic formula
to solve for $\sqrt{y}$,
not $y$:

$\sqrt{y}
=\dfrac{-\sqrt{x}\pm\sqrt{x+4}}{2}
$
so, squaring,
$y
=\dfrac{x\mp 2\sqrt{x}\sqrt{x+4}+x+4}{4}
=\dfrac{2x+4\mp 2\sqrt{x(x+4)}}{4}
=\dfrac{x+2\mp \sqrt{x(x+4)}}{2}
$.